# How to read mhtml files in Apache Server?

Tags: apache, xampp, mhtml

I use Xampp control panel to host an Apache server. I'm testing how to run mhtml files on a server. So far it only shows me raw text when visiting it on server side. I looked around on how to make it work but the solutions I got (for example, adding "AddType message/rfc822 .mhtml .mht" in http conf file) just proceeds to download the file instead of reading it.

Here's a sample of the initial block of the mhtml file:

```
From: <Saved by Blink>
Snapshot-Content-Location: https://www.instagram.com/jo0sef/
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Yousef=20AlSudais=20=D9=8A=D9=88=D8=B3=D9=81=20=D8=A7=D9=84=D8?=
 =?utf-8?Q?=B3=D8=AF=D9=8A=D8=B3=20(@jo0sef)=20=E2=80=A2=20Instagram=20pho?=
 =?utf-8?Q?tos=20and=20videos?=
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2021 08:18:55 -0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
    type="text/html";
    boundary="----MultipartBoundary--c1Osf7aCebmaZjjAXk0gfl7cuYp300joTDYRFPKyLF----"


------MultipartBoundary--c1Osf7aCebmaZjjAXk0gfl7cuYp300joTDYRFPKyLF----
Content-Type: text/html
Content-ID: <frame-AD05338F6D10E72FA62E6C2E3D66903E@mhtml.blink>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Location: https://www.instagram.com/jo0sef/
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I would love the browser to jsut read the file in and display it cleanly.

Comment: No unfortunately.